# Not getting the proper data from xml file from ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xml, loops

This is my JavaScript file

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open('GET','data.xml');

req.onreadystatechange = function(){

if ((req.status==200) && (req.readyState==4)){

```
    var items = req.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('name');   
    var output='<ul>';
        for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++){
            output += '<li>' +
            items[i].firstChild.nodeValue+ 
            '<li>';
        }
    output += '<ul>';
    document.getElementById("update").innerHTML=output;
}
```

}

req.send();

After running the above code i am not getting the proper data into the list.

Comment: Please define _proper_ and _inproper_ data.

Comment: i want get all the data from xml file to list using ajax i am very near to doing that

Comment: Why on earth having troubles with some code leads to a total stroke in communication skills too? How would we know, how your data looks, nor how it should look, if you're not explaining to us, what you expect to get, and what you get instead.

Comment: i dont know how to attach xml file data can you guide me